# How to end the Sip Call using sipstack

Tags: android, sip

I used the Android built-in sip library to write an app that makes calls via my  server. The calls are being made correctly, but most of the time, the calls aren't ended correctly.

This is my code to end the call:

```
public void stopCalling(){
    try {
        call.endCall();
        call.close();
    } catch (SipException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But it does not Ended properly.
Is there any other way to ended the sip call.

Comment: No there is no error return.It work randomly som time successfully end the call and some time not.

Comment: then there is some issue in your backend Asterisk server.

Comment: Check on your asterisk system if you're receiving hangup request from application or not. Also why you used `pjsip` tag in your question as your're using android build in sip stack library ?

Comment: I want to use the pjsip library but there is not receiver found for receiving the call so i used the sip stack for implementing the sip call functionality.Have you idea for receiving the sip call using the sip call?